# framework express changed BIGINT on db2 into String

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, express, db2

I was using express version "4.16.3" this qs vulnerable to Prototype Pollution appear and we move to "4.18.1" but some api's are getting error about the type of data now they are string and they were integer example:

> "MEMORY_example_GB": "0" against "MEMORY_example_GB": 0

on the database they are declared on the view in db2 as this BIGINT(ROUND(SUM(B.EXAMPLE) / 1024)) as MEMORY_example_GB

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to update the  `"body-parser": "^1.20.1"` since it was not parsing the answer as it should do.